# Trying to find an old (90s) TV episode - Woman brings back husband as headless android

Tags: story-identification, tv

It was a TV show with short stories.

The one in particular I'm looking for is an episode where a woman's husband dies and she brings him back to life as a headless android. He was a muscular military man. I just can't remember what show it was from.

Comment: Maybe Monsters https://trakt.tv/shows/monsters/seasons/3/episodes/9 The marriage of a couple of doctors become problematic when the woman's presumed-to-be-dead husband returns and she finds herself still allured to the hunk despite her better judgement. After finding success with animating a headless parrot, the two decide to use the numbskull of a third wheel to take their work to another level.